# How to customize port in filezilla to connect my vps?

Tags: ssh

The port of target vps is 28399 ,not 22 ,i want to connect it with filezilla.
I found that the port can only be 22 ，how can i customize the port ,make it to be 28399 or any other number?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to File >> Site Manager >> New Site >> fill the details in, >> select SFTP - SSH File Transfer Protocol >> Logon Type Normal >> Username and password

Then click on Connect. That will also save the connection for later use. You get to it the same way and you can rename it as well.

I think the quick connect assumes its FTP when you put in a non standard port.

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: no , i tested as you said .It can't work .

Comment: I am using that right now, do you get the same error? Make sure you select sftp, here is an example: http://i.imgur.com/51UU5zM.png (I added it to my answer above for your convenience)

Comment: Even in the quick connect bar, you can use `sftp://server:12345` in the textfield for the servername to specify the protocol and port to use.